# Iterating over a list with Stylus

Tags: stylus

I decided to switch over pre-compilers from SCSS => Stylus. I've already looked through the documentation for Stylus but have hit a block.

Stylus List:

```
breakpoints = xs 176px, 
              s 480px, 
              m 768px
```

This list is pulled like so:

```
respond-to()
    if arguments in breakpoints
        @media (min-width: arguments)
            {block}
    else 
        error('Invalid breakpoint.')
```

And references like so

```
respond-to(xs) 
    col()
```

But this outputs nothing.

I don't want to iterate through each array item and output them, I just want to match a user defined key name against the key name's in the array, and if it exists in the array output its single value into a statement, else error, as displayed above.

The code is logical, any ideas?

Edit #1: Tried converting the list to a **hash** and used the same pull statements, no luck

Hash:

```
breakpoints = { 'xs': 176px, 's': 480px, 'm ': 768px }
```

Pull:

```
respond-to()
    if arguments in breakpoints
        @media (min-width: breakpoints[arguments])
        {block}
    else 
        error('Invalid breakpoint.')
```

Edit #2: Found something similar to what I'm trying to do, just don't want that much code. CTRL F // Define the cache and the aliases [here.](http://kizu.ru/en/issues/new-stylus-features/)

Edit #3: Found a [NPM Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/at-breakpoint) which has the same usage

Comment: I don't recommend making the first line in your question one that asks us not to downvote it - at best that will make people automatically assume it's worthy of downvotes (plus your question seems fine).

Comment: Had some previous bad experiences last couple times on here with people even when the questions are worthwhile.

Comment: Why would you mention Sass at all?

Comment: Mentioning SASS was my way of identifying where my logic is being migrated from. Stylus is like the extreme version of it. I've removed any mention of it as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is a **list** of passed arguments, so you should use `[0]` to get the first argument. Or you can just name the argument. For example:

```
breakpoints = { 'xs': 176px, 's': 480px, 'm ': 768px }

respond-to() // or respond-to(bp) and delete the second line
  bp = arguments[0]
  if bp in breakpoints
    @media (min-width: breakpoints[bp])
      {block}
  else 
    error('Invalid breakpoint.')

+respond-to('xs') // the + sign is important because it's a block mixin call
  body
    color red
```

Comment: I will have to rewrite some of my scss, but your solution worked! And with less code than those other solutions. Thank you!